# Automatically deactive the internet at 9pm, but make it hard to activate it again

Tags: 18.04, internet, automation

Is there a solution that automatically deactivates my internet connection at a set time, but makes it sufficiently difficult to activate internet again, after I have deactivated it?
I would prefer a solution were it would take me about 5-10 minutes to activate the internet connection.

The reason I'm asking is that often times in the evening, I go on the internet and waste too much time there. Because in the evening I am already tired, I would not fit enough to make an effort for 5 minutes, to activate my internet connection, if I would have set in the afternoon, a timer, to automatically deactivate it at, say, 9pm, and would just go to sleep.
On the other hand, in the morning, when I'm energized, I would be happy to spend those minutes.

My machine is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Buy a lamp timer for your router. Any software solution you can implement means you can also defeat it with a simple `sudo`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your second half will create another script with reverse step to make it easy to reconnect. Honestly, that is crazy. Like I used to try reading books instead of quick search through the Internet. Internet usually drifts me to other random topics then loose time in that forest. Currently, I'm thinking about a home NAS server with content search feature, so looking inside e-books get easier like in the "Google effect" in the internet.

Comment: @PRATAP Via Router

Comment: @user535733 A lamp timer can be defeated even simpler, by just plugging the router directly into the socket. If the password is long enough, already `sudo` would be a good solution. But then the question remains: How can I automatically set my password in the evening from a short one, that I use during the day, to a long one, that will prevent me from using `sudo`.

Comment: @user.dz to use your terminology: I would look for something like a "one-way function script", that is easy to setup, and then hard to reverse.

Comment: @PRATAP My use case is that it's 8.30 pm and I think "I should turn the PC off; but let me just check the news first", and before I know it, it's 11 pm. So I would need what you mention:  a startup application to read the current time and if its over 9pm then currupt the network connection. But the caveat is, that between 9pm and 6am it should be hard to make the network connection work again (otherwise, if it can be undone in 2 clicks, I'll be tempted at 9:01 pm to simply turn whatever is stopping the network connection).

Comment: @PRATAP Hm... can that process be automatized, to uninstall it and password protect the package file? At 9pm, when I'm already tired, I won't have the energy to go through that to build up those obstacles, so it would have to be an automatic solution (in morning I will of course have the energy to undo all of that, so if uninstalling network manager in this way could be achieved, that would be a viable solution)

Comment: @PRATAP That sounds good. How can a script be made that, , when I run it, automatically uninstalls the network manager, and creates those directories? If you would have such a script, and post it as an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: yes, I will run the script myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Pluckeye](https://www.pluckeye.net)?

It is an Internet content filter. Its basic functionality is to block all images and videos to avoid distractions. It uses the exact same delay system you are mentioning, meaning any changes to the configuration you make are applied after the previously set delay time.

It has CLI and from what I know you can use it to control access to the internet connection.

From their FAQ:
[How can I completely cut off Internet access at night?](https://www.pluckeye.net/faq.html#sec-2-34)

Comment: It sounds perfect to me except one thing: I could simply uninstall pluckeye! Is there any way to make uninstalling it really hard? At least hard enough that it will take me 5 minutes to uninstall it? (In Android there's an app, AppBlock, that has something called a "Strict mode" than can be set for a given duration; during this time no system changes can be enforced; probably I would need something like that for Ubuntu as well. )

Comment: Well, I am no Linux expert, but you obviously can't remove it with `pluck uninstall` before previously set delay, `apt` doesn't seem to be able to do the job either, coz it doesn't see pluckeye at all. I tried removing /usr/bin/pluck which resulted only in losing interface to control it, every restriction stayed in place.
Of course, I don't believe that it is impossible, but maybe it would take you more than 5 minutes.

Comment: That sounds good, I will give it a shot an report back!